# Checking whether a string was already printed in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've faced some difficulties to create a code able to identify whether a string was already printed.

The purpose of the exercise is to add some words and count how many times that word was typed, but when print the results I'd like to show only the word not duplicated.

I have no idea about what's going on, the function isAdded always get as result true, even whether the strings are not equal, is there anybody that could help me?

```c
// Aluno: Diogo Ianhke
// Data: 01/12/2019

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Defines
#define qnt 12                                                         // Quantidade de palavras a serem armazenadas

// Prototype of functions
void store ();                                                         // Função para armazenar palavras inseridas pelo usuário
void cleaning (int result [qnt], char aux[qnt][20]);                   // Limpa lixo do vetor
int isAdded(char words[][20], int posicao);                            // Função para verificar se a palavra ja foi impressa

// Variables
char words [qnt][20];           // Armazena palavras fornecidas pelo usuário
char aux [qnt][20];             // Vetor auxiliar para verificar se a palavra ja foi impressa
int result [qnt];               // Armazena a incidência de cada palavra
int i, j, select, teste;
int percentual;

int main()
{
    while(1){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t1.Iniciar programa.\n\t2.Finalizar programa.\n\n\topcao desejada: ");
        scanf("%d",&select);

        switch (select)        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                store();                                         // Armazenas palavras inseridas pelo usuário
                system("cls");
                cleaning (result, aux);                          // Remove lixo dos vetores

                for (j=0;j<qnt;j++){                             // Conta quantas vezes cada palavra foi utilizada
                    for(i=0;i<qnt;i++){
                        if (strcmp(words[j], words[i]) == 0){
                            result[j] = result[j] + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (i=0;i<qnt;i++){
                    teste=isAdded(words,i);
                    percentual = (result[i]*100)/(qnt*1);
                    if (teste) printf("\n\t%s exibido (a): %d vez(es) ou %d%%\n", words[i],result[i], percentual);
                    strcpy(aux[i], words[i]);
                }
                printf("\n\n\n");
                system("pause");
            break;

            case 2:
                exit(0);
            break;

            default:
                system("cls");
                printf("\n\t Valor incorreto, a entrada deve ser 1 ou 2. \n\n\n");
                system("pause");
            break;

        } // END Switch
    } // END while function
    return 0;
} // END main function

void store (){

    for (i=0;i<qnt;i++){
        printf("\n\tDigite a palavra %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", words[i]);
        system("cls");
    }
    printf("\n\tNomes Armazenados com sucesso \n\n");
    ;
}

void cleaning (int result [qnt], char aux[qnt][20]){
    for (i=0;i<qnt;i++) {
        result[i] = 0;
        strcpy(aux[i],"\0");
    }
}

int isAdded(char words[][20], int posicao){
int i=0;
int flag = 0;
    for(i=0;i<(qnt-1);i++){
        if(strcmp(words[posicao],aux[i])==0){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

test 01: 
INPUTS: ARIEL, NANY, ARIEL
OUTPUT: ARIEL, NANY

test 02: 
INPUTS: ARIEL, ARIEL, NANY
OUTPUT: NOTHING

I followed a tip given by Gene about putting some printf along the code find bugs and fortunately, I could make it work partially.

When I put the same word in the sequence, it doesn't work.

Thank you for everybody who is helping me

Comment: Avoid buffer overflow: `scanf("%s", words[i]);` --> `scanf("%19s", words[i]);`. May help.  Please post sample input, output and output expected.

Comment: The first thing you should do is format your program more carefully and conventionally so that indent level and white space are uniform. Inconsistency hides silly errors. Then add `printf`s to emit information showing what the program is _actually_ doing. Your goal is to find the line of code where what you _think_ the program is doing and _what it actually does_ diverge. That will be the location of a bug. Then fix and repeat. If you have someone else spot the bug for you, you'll never gain this essential skill. You could also learn to use a debugger, an alternative to `printf`s.

Comment: put some comments above, thank you for helping me

Comment: Gene which debugger do you recommend?

Comment: `aux[i]!=NULL` might not work. you need the array to be at least one element bigger than `qnt`, or you will use off all the array without having space for NULL in it.

Comment: Serge thank you, I put a for and it worked partially

Comment: Thank you for everybody who helped me someway.